# Towns keeps crashing to desktop

Tags: pc, technical-issues, towns

I fell in love with the game *Towns*, except for one little thing: it keeps crashing for no apparent reason. There is no error message or warning, it just closes. I get my little people to build a town, boom, closed, all deleted. I auto-save now but it is still annoying.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the developers? They are quite easy to reach.

Comment: Have you tried anything to fix this yourself?  Checked the forums?  Anything at all?